# Time expression plus has/have

Tags: plural-forms, singular-vs-plural, measure-expressions

> Ten minutes have passed. Let's wait five more.

Is using have here correct?

Comment: This related ELU question may be useful: [*Is it “5–6 weeks are a lot of time” or “5–6 weeks is a lot of time”?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67553/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't find it problematic. Minutes are countable here. Thus using 'have' is okay.

However, you should say, "lets wait **for** five more (minutes).

Comment: Even though using ***have*** is "okay", it's still "problematic", because ***has*** is *also* okay. And I disagree with telling OP he "should" include ***for*** - it's entirely optional in this context, so there's nothing really beyond stylistic choice to favour either version. In some specific contexts, such as *Wait a minute! I don't think that's quite right!*, you'd practically *never* find anyone including ***for***.

Comment: *Let's wait (for) five more* .  Either way is OK in AmE too.  Without "minutes",  we'd probably not say "for" either.

Comment: Wait a minute is absolutely fine, but 'wait five more' still sounds strange my ears. Anyway, learned. Thanks to you too! :) @FumbleFingers But this forms a question.